# Add Entry Button Not Shown When Overriding Entry Sources

Tags: plugin-development, entries, control-panel

We're putting together a site where there is regional content managed by regional editors. I want to override the sources to only list entries from regions they are allocated to. I also want to group them by region rather than having entries for all their regions in one list.

All was going well until I tried to remove the default Craft sources by clearing the `$sources` array at the start. This has resulted in the New Entry button no longer being displayed.

This is my function at the moment:

```
public function modifyEntrySources(&$sources, $context)
{
    if ($context == 'index')
    {
        if ($this->regionalEd)
        {
            $sources = [];
            foreach ($this->regions as $region)
            {
                $sources[] = ['heading' => $region['title']];
                $sources['news:'.$region['id']] = [
                    'label'       => 'News',
                    'criteria'    => ['relatedTo' => $region['id'], 'section' => 'news', 'editable' => true],
                    'data'        => array('type' => SectionType::Channel, 'handle' => 'news'),
                    'defaultSort' => array('postDate', 'desc'),
                ];
                $sources['notifications:'.$region['id']] = [
                    'label'       => 'Notifications',
                    'criteria'    => ['relatedTo' => $region['id'], 'section' => 'notifications', 'editable' => true],
                    'data'        => array('type' => SectionType::Channel, 'handle' => 'notifications'),
                    'defaultSort' => array('postDate', 'desc'),
                ];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there something I need to add/remove, (other than the `$sources = [];` line!), to allow the New Entry button to be displayed?

Answer (score 1):

The New Entry button is not being displayed as Craft is not seeing my sources as containing publishable entries.

The Craft JS object contains a list of `publishableSections` which is checked by `craft.js` using `this.getSourceByKey('section:'+section.id)`. Since my sources use a custom `key` value they are not included in this list.

So I have resolved the problem by adding my own New Entry button.